# Gradle config to run Findbugs only on java but not scala

Tags: java, scala, gradle

my project contains both .java and .scala sources.

In order to allow references from java to scala the scala plugin is configured to compile both Java and Scala:

```
 sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/scala"]
 sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
 sourceSets.test.scala.srcDirs = ["src/test/java", "src/test/scala"]
 sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = []
```

How do I configure the Findbugs plugin to analyze only the java derived classes and omit the scala derived stuff? (Scala Source yields many false positive problems in findbugs analysis)

I tried 
    findbugs {
        sourceSets=["src/main/java"]
    }
but this results in a NPE in the Findbugs-Plugin

Comment: FindBugs analyzes class files, and since joint compilation writes all class files to the same directory, you'll have to find a way to tell which class files are Java and which are Scala. Gradle doesn't ship with support for this, but perhaps there is a Scala tool/library that can help with it.

Alternatively, perhaps there is a way to configure the Scala compiler to write the class files to different output directories. Then you'll still have to figure out how to make the Gradle build aware of that fact.

Comment: Yet another solution would be to compile the Java code a second time (this time with the Java compiler), and pass the resulting class files to FindBugs.

Comment: If your scala code lives in its own packages you could use a FindBugs exclude filter file http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html